# Control mouse on remote windows server

Tags: python, windows, remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

I need to run GUI application on remote windows host and then do some actions with mouse and keyboard. This should be done from local pc without opening any GUI application (for example "Remote Desktop Connection").

So I have a python script on remote server which does all the actions I need (tested on local pc) and I run the script via psexec which successfully opens the GUI application on server.

**The problem is that when python tries to programatically move and click mouse it throws an exception because there is no screen.**

Actions with keyboard (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V) can be done successfully.

Here is the code that I use to simulate mouse click but as I mentioned it doesn't work on server because there is no actual screen.

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: So what have you tried thus far to solve the task in which you ask us to solve?

Comment: @Torxed I don't ask you to solve anything for me I ask for suggestion. I tried win32api to simulate mouse click programatically but as I mentioned because there is no screen it didn't work.

win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

Comment: That's much better. Before you asked us to suggest you a solution wich basically is either opinion based or you ask us to do the coding for you - Both of which isn't allowed here (read the FAQ) : ) But that's much better, add that code to your question.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Use UI Automation instead of faking input.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting directly to user32.dll through ctypes  and use mouse controlling functions from there. Perhaps win32types problem is that it is mostly statically linked to MS API. So it is programmed for desktop environment.

Also, you can try pymouse module that you can find on pypi.python.org, of course, which does the same as I suggested above.